# Xamarin 2.0 Iphone resource prefix

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have installed Xamarin 2.0 and i can now starte the iphone simulator from visual studio. I have added another Iphone resource prefix to my project Resources;images
When i run the app from Visual studio the resources in the images folder is not included in the app. If i run it from Xamarin studio on the mac, it all works fine. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Xamarin.iOS addin for VS. I [filed it](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11143).